# How to calculate thd average of a Wilson loop in LQCD?

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, lattice-model, wilson-loop

I'm am trying to do the excercise in page 35 from Lepage's LQCD notes: http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-lat/0506036. 
I want to compute the thermal average of the Wilson loop of size $a\times a$, where $a$ is the lattice spacing. 
The action is
$$S=k \sum P_{\mu\nu}$$
Where $k$ is a constant and the sum is over all possible plaquettes. So the value to calculate is
$$\frac 1 Z \int W(C) e^{-S}$$
This would be done using a Metropolis Monte Carlo algorithm.
My doubts are:

- Where am I supposed to locate the Wilson loop?
- How does the lattice spacing affect the result? It seems that it would only change a multiplicative constant in the action.

Is there any paper with an explained implementation or code?

Answer (score 0):

The location of the Wilson loop is arbitrary. If your lattice is periodic, it will be translationally invariant. (If it is not, boundary effects may cause trouble.)

Due to the renormalization group, we know there is a link between the coupling constant (which in your case is hidden in $k$), and the cut-off (which is the lattice spacing in this case). This means that taking the correct limit in $k$ (that would be $k\to\infty$ if I'm not mistaken) will recover the continuum limit.